# How to convert jpeg image to PICT image on MAC using Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, sips

How to convert JPEG image to PICT image using cocoa.Some script is given below.

```
NSData *imgData = [NSData datawithContentsOfFile:@"/var/root/Desktop/1.jpeg"];
NSPICTImageRep *imagerep = [NSPICTImageRep imageRepWithData:imgData];
NSData *data = [imageRep PICTRepresentation];
[data writeTofile:@"/var/root/Desktop/save.pict" atomically:No];
```

This script is not work. and any other alternate method which convert jpeg image to pict image without Applescript.

.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple problems with your code.

#1) are you *certain* of the location of that "`1.jpeg`" file?

#2) you're not looking at the error result of your "`writeToFile`".  On my machine, I can not write to anything inside the "`/var/root`" directory.

Once you fix up the source and destination paths, you should change your code to something like this:

```
NSData *imgData = [NSData datawithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/anuj/Desktop/1.jpeg"];
NSPICTImageRep *imagerep = [NSPICTImageRep imageRepWithData:imgData];
NSData *data = [imageRep PICTRepresentation];
NSLog(@"my image data size is %ld", [data length]);
if([data length] > 0)
{
   BOOL success = [data writeTofile:@"/Users/anuj/Desktop/save.pict" atomically:NO];
   if(success)
       NSLog(@"successfully wrote the file");
   else
       NSLog(@"did not write the file");
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"didn't convert the image to a Pict");
}
```

Comment: I am working on root not User. and your script is not run on user login.

Comment: Why would you do this as root?!

Comment: I am develop the Image convertor software which run on user and root.So, My pict image is convert to another format on user and root ptah.